How to Calculate Oracle Database size Tables ,Indexes, TABLE PARTITION,LOBSEGMENT and LOB PARTITION with out free space
We have huge table in Oracle Database and we have deleted millions of records in the table.Before deleting and after deleting there is no difference in size and no of records. We haven't used Shrink command.
How to calculate realistic size of the table.
I have tried below query
SELECT
   OWNER, 
   TABLE_NAME, 
   TRUNC(SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024) SIZE_IN_MB
FROM
(SELECT SEGMENT_NAME TABLE_NAME, OWNER, BYTES
 FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
 WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
group by OWNER, TABLE_NAME


Deleting rows doesn't free up space to the tablespace. The space is reusable within their existing blocks, but the blocks are still allocated to the table segment. If you use conventional inserts, this space can be reused by new rows, but if you use direct path inserts, it will never be reused. To remove the extra space, you'd need to reorg the table with a move command:
alter table mytable move parallel (degree 16) update indexes;
If you have to do this while the app is doing DML on the table, you can add an online clause to it. Otherwise omit. This is by far the best way to recondition a table after it undergoes some kind of fragmentation (deletes, row chaining, decompression, etc..)
In the future, avoid mass deletes as a typical activity. If you are archiving old rows, consider using partitioning instead so you can simply drop an old partition.
If it was a one-time activity and involved a significant portion of the table, it's always better to CTAS (create table as select) a new table with rows you want to keep and swap with the old one, than to do an actual delete. Or CTAS, truncate old, insert append back into old if you don't want to recreate indexes, triggers, constraints, grants, etc.. But either way, segment recreation (which involve direct path inserts only) is always more efficient than large-scale deletes (or updates), and prevent the table from getting fragmented or into a condition requiring a move to fix it.

Paul's answer is very good. I'll just add some conceptual information.
Blocks are usually formatted and filled as needed, from the beginning to the end of the segment. The "high water mark" points to the last formatted block of the segment (even when the content of this block has already been deleted, as it's probably in your case).
DML operations (INSERT, UPDATE, etc) can use partially (or totally) emptied blocks under this "high water mark", but they don't move down the mark. When you do a full scan, Oracle reads through the mark (even when some or even all blocks under the mark are empty). A "direct insert", as Paul said, always write ABOVE the mark.
The ALTER TABLE SHRINK command is the only way (besides TRUNCATE) of moving down the "high water mark" (as much as possible, towards the beginning of the segment). This will speed up full scans and it'll allow the direct inserts to reuse the freed space. But this space will remain inside the segment, and it won't be returned to the tablespace until you execute a subsequent ALTER TABLE DEALLOCATE UNUSED.
The choice between this reorganization method and those suggested by Paul depends on your specific needs, the rate and volume of your deletes, etc.

Said this, there are ways of knowing (approximately) the actually filled/empty space inside the segment.
